# How do I export the output of an async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am running the following code. Where I am expecting to see the outputs `latitude` and `longitude`, what I get is `Promise{<pending>}` in my console. Why is this the case? I thought using `async/await` helps to eliminate the problem of pending promises since the code can't go forward until the promise fulfills. How do I solve this problem?

```js
const issURL = 'someUrl';
async function getData() {
            const res = await fetch(issURL);
            const data = await res.json();
            const {
                latitude,
                longitude
            } = data;
            return (latitude, longitude);
        }
console.log(getData());
```

Comment: You need to `await` your call to `getData()` as well

Comment: Or `.then(res => console.log(res))`. If you're trying to make the function return a value synchronously, that's not possible\*.

Comment: Calls to async functions will return the result wrapped in a promise, so you'll have to `await` your call to `getData()` to get the result.

Comment: Note that the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in JavaScript will evaluate all comma-separated statements, but only return the result of the final statement. Therefore you only return `longitude` in `getData()`. Did you mean to return an object created in [object literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#object_literal_notation_vs_json)?

Comment: @ElanHamburger okay, that means I can only get what I want by calling getData() within another async function?

Comment: @OskarGrosser you were right. So how can I return an object like you said?

Comment: Use `{}` instead of `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the getData() function needs some time to resolve its promise, you have to `await` it as well. Alternatively, you can use `getData().then((res) => console.log(res))`